# Rearrange page layout when the content element width and height vary dynamically using Isotope

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I have a page built using bootstrap 3 which has feeds updated by various users. The content may be either text only or image only or a combination of both. These elements have various heights, but I have set a certain max-height. The extra long divs can be expanded by clicking a button. I use Isotope to randomly arrange these elements in my page and everything works fine. But when I try to expand the extra long divs, the layout remains static instead of adjusting to the new height.

This is my code

```
if ($('.container').length) {
        $('.container').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.container-item',
            layoutMode: 'masonry'
        });
    }
```

Do I have to do something to detect the change in height to tell isotope to rearrange the layout !! Please help me since I've been trying to make this work from past 3 days, but with no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you have declared css width property assign the values with percentage, so that it will adjust accordingly to the width of the viewport

Comment: the problem is not the width, it's the height. Since I use built in bootstrap classes for width, everything is in percentage and responsive.......

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example on isotope main site](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout):

```
$( function() {

  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100
    }
  });

  $container.on( 'click', '.item', function() {
    // change size of item by toggling gigante class
    $( this ).toggleClass('gigante');
    $container.isotope('layout');
  });

});
```

If you collapse a box using jQuery to expand Its height you could have a callback once is finished and use $container.isotope("layout"); so that isotope reLayouts recalculating the available space.

Codepen by the author http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qzhIb

Comment: thank you for that example. I just need a clarification. In the example, on click of the .item the author toggles a class .gigante which has a predefined fixed height and width. But in my case only the width is fixed, height depends on the content......can you please guide me how I can modify accordingly !!

Comment: How are you expanding the box height? If you expand it via jquery you could use a callback once the box has finished expanding and then do $container.isotope("layout"); also updated my answer.